# Defining cookie name in one place

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I'm trying to define my cookie name in one place (config.php) so that if i need to change the name i only have to do it once. I have:

```
define('THEME_COOKIE','test');
```

I am then trying to use this string constant as the name of my cookie, however it is not working...

```
setcookie(THEME_COOKIE, base64_encode(json_encode($user)), time() + (86400 * 30), '/', '', false, true);
```

The cookie name is just showing up as THEME_COOKIE instead of test..

Any ideas?

Comment: There should be a log in php_error if it uses THEME_COOKIE as a string instead of your constant... Are you sure your config file is readen beofre your setcookie ?

Comment: php standardism - undefined constants are assumed to be unquoted strings. if theme_cookie showing up as the actual string theme_cookie, then you haven't run your define() yet to create that constant. e.g. your config isn't included or executed yet. You SHOULD have gotten a warning from this, which means that `display_errors` and `error_reporting` are disabled. they should never be off while debugging/developing.

Comment: config is included correctly and is the first file that is read...

Comment: Did you have a look at the php logs ?

Comment: There are no errors, it's just interpreting the constant as a string everytime...